# How to set my LoginPage as index in Expo React Native

Tags: react-native, expo, expo-router

I have an app on React-Native (using Expo) that is pretty basic. as for now, I have an Index.js with all the logic of a login page. That works great but I want to structure it more into different screens. So under my directory `app` I have a `(login)` group and inside of `(login)` I have `_layout.js` and I have `LoginScreen.js`

[image]

I want to set my login page as the index, on which the user see's the login page, instead of having all the logic on the `index.js` just for better structure. Now I am doing based on what I read online, but if there's any better to structure screens please let me know.

Continuing with the issue, I have this on my *`layout` in the `app`directory*

```
import { Stack, useRouter } from 'expo-router';
import { Button, Image, View } from 'react-native';
import LoginStack from './(login)/_layout';

const StackLayout = () => {
    const router = useRouter();

    return (
        <Stack
            initial="(login)" // Set the initial screen to be the Login screen
        >
            <Stack.Screen
                name="(login)"
                component={LoginStack} // Associate the LoginStack component with this screen
                options={{
                    headerShown: false,
                }}
            />
                
            <Stack.Screen
                name="register"
                options={{
                    headerTitle: 'Create account',
                    headerRight: () => <Button title="Open" onPress={() => router.push('/modal')} />
                }}
            />

            <Stack.Screen
                name="(tabs)"
                options={{
                    headerShown: false,
                }}
            />
        </Stack>
    );
};

export default StackLayout;
```

And this is what I have inside of my `app/(login)/_layout.js`

```
import { Stack, useRouter } from 'expo-router';
import { Button, Image, View } from 'react-native';
import LoginStack from './../(login)/_layout';

const StackLayout = () => {
  const router = useRouter();

  return (
    <Stack
      initial="(login)"
    >
      <Stack.Screen name="(login)">
        {() => <LoginStack />}
      </Stack.Screen>
    </Stack>
  );
};

export default StackLayout;
```

All of this results in this error:

```
<Screen /> component in `default export` at `app/_layout` must not have a `children`, `component`, or `getComponent` prop when used as a child of a Layout Route
```

I tired using the `Stack` and `Stack.screen`. On which that `Stack` is wrapping the component. SOme of the issues I also encountered was:

```
Error: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports.

Check the render method of `AppLayout`.
```

Now I am not an expert in react-native (expo) - I've tried some AI explanations but they all play around with different answers. So if a kind human like to explain a bit it will be nice.

So basically two things, 1. Setting a login page as an index - 2. Suggestion as how to structure the pages for great maintainability.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use Redirect from expo-router to redirect user once they hit to index page. If index page does not contain anything to render it will feel like login page is the first page that is loaded. Example usage :

`<Redirect href={"login"} />`
where you need to change the name of login to whatever page you want to re-direct users. Just don't forget to import it
`import { Redirect } from "expo-router"`